# Will I keep skill points from books and trainers after respeccing?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

When i get some skill points in for example Blacksmithing, Detect Hidden etc by reading books and using trainers, will i get those skill points back when i respec my char at fatewaever? Or those points will be gone?

Comment: It's been a long time, but from what I recall those points are permanent.  They will stay in those skills forever, even if you respec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skill points from racial bonuses, books, trainers and twists of fate are permanent & non-transferable. Only points from leveling can be redistributed. When you respec they are added to your base stats for the skill the same as your racial allocation from when you created your character.

So for example, you choose a bonus at the beginning of the game for +2 Blacksmithing, read a book and visited 2 trainers. When you respec, you will find you have 5 points locked into smithing.